# After refreshing the page: {"success":true,"data":[]}

Tags: angular, routes

After refreshing **http://localhost:4200/user/products/$%7Buserid%7D** , the page displays:

{"success":true,"data":[]}

code **src/app/product/product.module.ts**

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: `user/products`, canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: UserProductsComponent 
  }, {
    path: `user/products/:id`, canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: UserProductsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserProductsComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    UserProductsComponent,
    FormsModule]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

code **app.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [ 
   { path: '', component: NavbarComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CoreModule,
    UserModule,
    ProductModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard, UserService, ProductsService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

code **auth.guard.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.checkLoggedIn(state.url);
  }

  checkLoggedIn(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn_()) {
      return true;
    }       
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
  }
}
```

code **src/app/product/user-products/user-products.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() { 
   this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;
   this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => { 
      if (params.id) { 
          this.productid = params['_id'];       
          this.getProducts(this.userObj.userid); 
      } 
   }); 
}
```

How should I correct for the `user/products/:id` page to work? Authorization of this page is poorly made?

Comment: Where is your request?

Comment: **src/app/product/user-products/user-products.ts** : `ngOnInit() {
    this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      if (params.id) {       
        this.productid = params['_id'];        
        this.getProducts(this.userObj.userid);
      }
    });`

Comment: are you sure you have data stored into you database?

Comment: data is retrieved from the database correctly. Adding, editing, deleting, displaying data works. In case of just refreshing the page, this message appears: `{"success": true, "data": []}`

Comment: I'm not sure, but this method probably does not work correctly. `this.getProducts(this.userObj.userid);` does not hold the authorization key. I don't know how to improve it.

Comment: I think your problem is where you implemented this.authService.isLoggedIn_(). if you add a if (this.authService.isLoggedIn_()) {
      return true;
    } and you are still able to see product detail, then there is a problem in your auth implementation.

Comment: What is the returned value of your this.userObj?

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;
    console.log( 'this.userObj');
    console.log( this.userObj);
}`
**returns:**
`{userid: "5ab655bbb94733156c438112", username: "rrrr", password: "$2a$05$0gJT/u8QPdgqYzobifFtgOGwQi1h3m4FuZetK4D8YvGRtzdGhNqB2", description: "", email: "rrrr", …}`

Answer (score 0):

If your path really is

```
user/products/:id
```

then you have to get the 'id' without underscore in your user-products.ts. And you certainly won't use the userId to get products, do you? ;)

```
if (params.id) { 
    this.productid = params['id']; // << no underscore for the id!        
    this.getProducts(this.productid); // << get products by productId not by userId
}
```

This should do.

Comment: I correct: `ngOnInit () {this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser; this.route.params.subscribe ((params: any) => {if (params.id) {this.productid = params ['_ id']; this.getProducts (this.productid);}}); } `but still after the refresh appears on the page: `{"success": true, "data": []}`

Comment: But you still use "this.productid = params ['_ id'];" This is wrong. Please replace it by "this.productid = params ['id'];"  Don't use underscore here, because in your link the param is named 'id' and not '_id'!

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.userObj = this.authService.currentUser;  
    console.log( this.userObj);
    this.route.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
      if (params.id) {     
        this.productid = params['id'];      
        this.getProducts(this.productid);
      }
    });
}` I improved, but it still does not work

Comment: Well, then I'd suggest to have a look on the server side. I'd bet that either the id doesn't exist or the service you call is malfunctious.

Comment: yes, the `req.params.id` parameter returns:
`${userid}` `[]`
after refreshing the page. The first call returns the value correctly.

Comment: Oh! I see. So, when you access the page for the first time, you get a value? I do ask this, because your headline says that a refresh causes the problem.

Comment: yes, the first time is the value in `req.params.id`, after refreshing he gets `${userid}`